# How did Fuu die in Naruto?

Tags: naruto

How did Fuu die in the *Naruto* anime? Was she killed by the Akatsuki during the bijuu extraction or was it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [Fu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/F%C5%AB) was captured by the Akatsuki, her death shortly followed after the extraction of the tailed beast within her.

> Fū was subsequently captured, and had her tailed beast extracted from her body and sealed within the Demonic Statue of the Outer Path, resulting in her death